# Saving values from spark to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, pyspark, datastax

I need to store the values from kafka->spark streaming->cassandra.

Now, I am receiving the values from kafka->spark and I have a spark job to save values into the cassandra db. However, I'm facing a problem with the datatype dstream.

In this following snippet you can see how I'm trying to convert the DStream into python friendly list object so that I can work with it but it gives an error.

input at kafka producer:

> Byrne 24 San Diego robbyrne@email.com Rob

spark-job:

```
map1={'spark-kafka':1}
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(stream, 'localhost:2181', "name", map1)
lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))

words.pprint() # outputs-> Byrne 24 SanDiego robbyrne@email.com Rob

list=[lambda word for word in words]
#gives an error -> TypeError: 'TransformedDStream' object is not iterable
```

**This is how I'm saving values from spark->cassandra**

```
rdd2=sc.parallelize([{
... "lastname":'Byrne',
... "age":24,
... "city":"SanDiego",
... "email":"robbyrne@email.com",
... "firstname":"Rob"}])
rdd2.saveToCassandra("keyspace2","users")
```

What's the best way of converting the DStream object to a dictionary or what's the best way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

I just need the values received from kafka (in the form of DStream) to be saved in Cassandra.

Thanks and any help would be nice!

Versions:

```
Cassandra v2.1.12
Spark v1.4.1
Scala 2.10
```

Comment: Because it was my mistake, more related to $JAVA_HOME problem than mesos.

Comment: Okay man relax. No reason to get hyper here. Let's not spam this post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer in this tutorial http://katychuang.me/blog/2015-09-30-kafka_spark.html.

Comment: @HackCode-  I'm also trying to execute same example but I'm facing error at saveToCassandra('keyspace','table') line.Error - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.newInstance. what I'm missing can you suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Like everything 'sparky', I think a short explanation is due since even if you are familiar with RDDs, DStreams are of an even higher concept:
A Discretized Stream (`DStream`), is a continuous sequence of RDDs of the same type, representing a continuous stream of data. In your case, DStreams are created from live Kafka data.
While a Spark Streaming program is running, each DStream periodically generates a RDD from live Kafka data

Now, to iterate over received RDDs, you need to use `DStream#foreachRDD` (and as implied by its name, it serves a similar purpose as *foreach*, but this time, to iterate over **RDDs**).
Once you have an RDD, you can invoke `rdd.collect()` or `rdd.take()` or any other standard API for RDDs.

Now, as a closing note, to make things even more fun, Spark introduced a new receiver-less “direct” approach  to ensure stronger end-to-end guarantees.
(`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` which requires Spark 1.3+)
Instead of using receivers to receive data, this approach periodically queries Kafka for the latest offsets in each topic+partition, and accordingly defines the offset ranges to process in each batch. When the jobs to process the data are launched, Kafka’s simple consumer API is used to read the defined ranges of offsets from Kafka.
(which is a nice way to say you will have to "mess" with the offsets yourself)

See [Direct Streams Approach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers) for further details.
See [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala) for a scala code example

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc of the **spark-cassandra** connector: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(n))

val stream = ...

val wc = stream
        .map(...)
        .filter(...)   
        .saveToCassandra("streaming_test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count")) 

ssc.start()
```